How can I put each link in its dictionary key?
I am scraping a page and i want to save each link in its own dict key but i do not know how to do it
this the complete code
download_info_list = []
download_info = {"nombre": [], "juego": [], "dlc": [], "update": []}
# localizar el siguiente link para sacarle su href e ir a esa pagina
second_download_links = page.query_selector(
    ".elementor-button.elementor-button-link.elementor-size-sm.elementor-animation-float")
second_download_links_href = second_download_links.get_attribute("href")
page.goto(second_download_links_href)

time.sleep(3)

# localizar los siguientes links para sacarles su href y que sean guardados en un archivo
last_download_links = page.query_selector_all(".wp-block-button__link.wp-element-button")
last_download_links_href = [download_link.get_attribute("href") for download_link in last_download_links]

# localizar los span y sacarle el texto
span_elements = page.query_selector_all("a > span")
span_elements = [span.inner_text().lower() for span in span_elements]

for span in span_elements:
    if "dlc" in span:
        download_info["dlc"].append(span_elements)
    elif "update" in span:
        download_info["update"].append(span)
    else:
        download_info["juego"].append(span)

# añadir el link del juego y el nombre
game_title = page.query_selector("h1")
game_title_text = game_title.inner_text()

download_info["nombre"].append(game_title_text)

print(download_info)

Here is the a element that contains the links i want to scrape:
<a class="wp-block-button__link wp-element-button" href="https://1fichier.com/?r2vattfxsdxyq6vp39un&amp;af=2850246" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="appearance: none; background: rgb(223, 156, 100); border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); box-shadow: none; box-sizing: inherit; color: white; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0.0125em; line-height: 1.4; padding: 12px 24px; position: relative; text-decoration-line: none; text-transform: uppercase; transition: background 0.3s ease 0s, color 0.3s ease 0s, border 0.3s ease 0s; vertical-align: middle;" target="_blank"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">1 FICHIER</span></a>

i did that for to test how it went and it worked, but now i want to do it with the links (last_download_links_href) but i don't know how
I tried to use zip() but the links were saved where they wanted to be saved, almost all links where saved in the "nombre" key, i do not know what i am doing wrong

yes, i want to save the download_info into the download_info_ list and then saved it as a json in a file @Wonka

i dont get it @Wonka

if you mean the download_info it would be like this
download_info = {"nombre": [game name], "juego": [game link], "dlc": [game dlc], "update": [game update]}
it would be like that, but if try to do it, i dont get the output i want, i can show you:
{'nombre': ['13 - XIII REMAKE ➡️ [NSP] - [7.42GB] - [ENLACES VIP] + UPDATE 1.6.8166 |  NINTENDO PROJECT | EL UNICO PROYECTO DE NINTENDO'], 'juego': [['https://1fichier.com/?r2vattfxsdxyq6vp39un&af=2850246', 'https://megaup.net/1O2as/XIII_[01006CA00E9FA800][v65536][US].nsp.rar'],
as you can se i have to links in the first key,

f you mean the download_info it would be like this download_info = {"nombre": [game name], "juego": [game link], "dlc": [game dlc], "update": [game update]}

Please [edit] the post to show output structures and the website you're scraping. Without the site, it's all guesswork since just about anything can go wrong. The code here is not complete as advertised since there's no way to run it. Thanks!

thank you for answering @ggorlen but i cant show the whole code because the page im sraping needs my account to show the links i want to get ;(. The code i showed its ok, its taking every link i want to take, the only problem i have is how to append every link in its dict key, just this

Why can't you process last_download_links_href similarly to the way you do span_elements?

@Barmar,because to know the links I want to grab I have to know the text that is inside that span, that span is inside a, and contains dlc or update text, that's why I use span, but I don't know how to do it for the href above.

It would help if you showed some sample HTML and the desired result. The question is currently too vague to answer.

ok, i will edit the question

i edited it @Barmar

I understand. Can you try to reproduce the relevant behavior and/or provide a bit more HTML context? Thanks.
